# Google Sheets - Calculate sum of row results - by using one-liner formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In some column have formula like below:

```
=SUM(MMULT(IFNA(FILTER($H$2:$H;$G$2:$G=M2);0);L2))
```

I have expanded it in 3 rows (A1:A3):

```
=SUM(MMULT(IFNA(FILTER($H$2:$H;$G$2:$G=M2);0);L2))
=SUM(MMULT(IFNA(FILTER($H$2:$H;$G$2:$G=M3);0);L3))
=SUM(MMULT(IFNA(FILTER($H$2:$H;$G$2:$G=M4);0);L4))
```

And I'm getting right results.
Then I want to get sum of those. But I need to create all of above in one line.
I mean - I don't want to calculate above separately and then do something like SUM(A1:A3).

I was trying with ARRAYFORMULA() but with no success, yeah, how hard can it be, right?

Have a nice evening!

**UPDATE:**

If someone will look for the solution, the best one is Mike's solution. Take a look at picture what he has added.

I have just extended it to filter L and M columns and it does not matter how long columns are. Of course L and M columns have to have the same number of elements ;)

```
=SUM(MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(--(G2:G=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(M2:M;ISTEXT(M2:M))))*(H2:H));FILTER(L2:L;ISNUMBER(L2:L))))
```

Comment: please share a sample sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=sum(mmult(arrayformula(--(G2:G=transpose(M2:M4))*(H2:H)),L2:L4))
```

the formula `=arrayformula(--(G2:G=transpose(M2:M4))*(H2:H))` will give you a matrix as follows, then apply mmult
[image]

Comment: The formula is working and looks really professional! Thank you and sorry that I did not provide the sample sheet.
I'm not sure why did you use "--"?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to nest the evaluations inside a SUM, like the below and get a SUM of the SUM's so to speak.

```
=SUM(SUM(MMULT(IFNA(FILTER($H$2:$H;$G$2:$G=M2);0);L2)),SUM(MMULT(IFNA(FILTER($H$2:$H;$G$2:$G=M3);0);L3)),SUM(MMULT(IFNA(FILTER($H$2:$H;$G$2:$G=M4);0);L4)))
```

There probably is a more efficient way, but why over complicate it. :)